# Looking for RAW features or items that allow a PC to modify the outcome of a d4+1 that also isn't damage

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, class-feature, feats

I'm looking at Time Stop and wondering if there is any way at all to modify the rolled d4+1. I know that Extend Spell doesn't work because the duration is Instantaneous despite the extra rounds it gives you to act.

Any RAW feature, item, or spell by WotC that will allow someone to modify (or re-roll) a die, without requiring that die to be a d20, ability check, attack roll, saving throw, or damage is a helpful answer to the main question, even if it for some reason specifically can't or doesn't work with Time Stop which gave me the idea for the question.

Comment: You may also desire to explicitly rule out *wish* in your question, as it's usually a bit of a cop-out answer in cases like this

Comment: Could you please narrow down the question a bit? Do you want to prolong the Time Stop effect duration? Or was it an abstract question about possible ways to reroll *any* die in 5e?

Comment: @enkryptor The latter, sort of; Time Stop was just the motivator to the question, since I'm fairly certain there are other such qualifying die rolls in the game (as an example, the 1d4 from bless). I'm not looking to reroll *any* die; just die that meet the criteria given (usually but not necessarily only in spells).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### There is no such feature

Checking all the published rules expansions and settings, as of this writing I believe there is no published spell, feature or item that would allow to reroll any die, outside of the cop-out options of *wish* or Divine Intervention, both of which require your DM to play along.

The closest I found to a general non-Save/Attack/Skill or damage reroll is the Empowered Healing feature of the Divine Soul sorcerer that allows you to spend 1 sorcery point to reroll any allied roll within 5 feet that is rolled to restore hit points, no matter the dice used, but that still will not allow you to reroll the number of turns on *time stop*.